# Remove nullability from generic type parameter

Tags: kotlin, generics

Is there a way to remove nullability from generic parameter?

```kotlin
interface Test<A: Any?> {
   fun <B> surelyNotNull(): B // must be T for any nullable type T?
}
// usage
val test: Test<String?> = TODO()
test.surelyNotNull() // should return non-nullable String
```

Comment: What do you want to do if this passed type is null? This null type means that you have to somehow deal with it, you can't just ignore it

Comment: I want to make builder for validation library. i.e. `ValidatorBuilder<A> { fun notNull(): ValidatorBuilder<B> }`. After `notNull()` we obviously deal with non-nullable type and question is how to represent it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to achive and how do you want to use this, but how about this?

```
interface ValidationBuilder<A : Any> {
    fun validate(a: A?): A
}

class NotNulLValidator<A : Any> : ValidationBuilder<A> {
    override fun validate(a: A?): A {
        if (a == null) throw IllegalArgumentException()
        return a
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about specifying a non-nullable generic type in the `interface`? You would need to mark any null-returning methods accordingly.

```kotlin
interface Test<A : Any> {
   fun maybeNull(): A?
   fun surelyNotNull(): A
}

val test: Test<String> = TODO()
val notNullable: String = test.surelyNotNull()
val nullable: String? = test.maybeNull()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can express it as an extension method:

```
fun <A : Any> ValidatorBuilder<A?>.surelyNotNull(): ValidatorBuilder<A> = TODO()
```

Though in this case you can't implement it for some `ValidatorBuilder` differently from another.